# In Pairs ou Ipairs

Tags: lua

Há alguma diferença entre `in ipairs` e `in pairs`?
Qual?

```
a = {1, "b", 3, "d"}
for i, v in pairs(a) do print(i, v) end
print("Ipairs")
for i, v in ipairs(a) do print(i, v) end
```

Retorna:

```
1   1
2   b
3   3
4   d
Ipairs
1   1
2   b
3   3
4   d
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ipairs` percorre as entradas com índices inteiros numa tabela, em ordem.

`pairs` percorre todas as entradas numa tabela, em ordem arbitrária.

No seu exemplo, adicione `a.teste=true`depois de criar a tabela ou `teste=true` na criação. O par `teste,true` será visitado por `pairs` mas não por `ipairs`.

Comment: Só pra complementar, fiz o teste no http://ideone.com/eixTay